# Show that $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1$ and $3x + 9yz = 5$ intersect at precisely two points.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations

For part A, I've tried solving each equation for $x$, then replacing $x^2$ in one equation with the squared results of the other, but have reached a point from which I have no idea how to proceed.

Since I kind of need the results of part A (or at least part B) to solve the rest of the questions, I'm just a bit stuck.

Note that I've also tried solving for $x$ and setting the equations equal to each other, as well as solving for $x^2$ and doing the same. They lead back to the same result.

For part B, I... I don't even know what's going on with $y=\frac{2}{3}$.

---

#### The Questions

a. By hand, show that $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $3x + 9yz = 5$ intersect at precisely two points.

b. Find these two points of intersection, exactly.

c. Show that the two surfaces have common tangent planes at those respective points.

d. Find the equations of the two common tangent planes.

e. Use *Mathematica* to give a "good" graph of the two surfaces, along with the tangent planes.

---

#### My Work

**Part A**
$x^2 = 1-y^2-z^2$

$3x = 5-9yz$
$x = \frac{5}{3} - 3yz$
$x^2 = \frac{25}{9} - 10yz + 9y^2z^2$

$\frac{25}{9}-10yz+9y^2z^2=1-y^2-z^2$
$\frac{16}{9} = 10yz-9y^2z^2-y^2-z^2$

**Part B**
$y = \frac{2}{3}$ ---> $x = \frac{5}{3}-3(\frac{2}{3})z = \frac{5}{3} - 2z$

$\frac{25}{9}+\frac{4}{9}-\frac{20z}{3}-4z^2+z^2=1$
$\frac{29}{9}-\frac{20z}{3}-3z^2=1$
$\frac{29-60z-27z^2}{9}=1$
$29-60z-27z^2=9$
$20-60z-27z^2=0$
$z^2-\frac{20z}{9}-\frac{20}{27}+\frac{20}{27}=0+\frac{20}{27}$
$z^2-\frac{20z}{3}+(\frac{10}{9})^2=(z+\frac{10}{9})^2=\frac{160}{81}$
$z + \frac{10}{9} = \sqrt{\frac{160}{81}} = \frac{-10±4\sqrt{10}}{9}$

$z = \frac{-10+4\sqrt{10}}{9}$ ---> $x = \frac{35-8\sqrt{10}}{9}$
$z = \frac{-10-4\sqrt{10}}{9}$ ---> $x = \frac{35+8\sqrt{10}}{9}$

.
$y = \frac{-2}{3}$ ---> $x = \frac{5}{3}+2z$
$\frac{25}{9}+\frac{4}{9}+\frac{20z}{3}+4z^2+z^2=1$
$\frac{29}{9}+\frac{20z}{3}+5z^2=1$
$\frac{29+60z+45z^2}{9}=1$
$29+60z+45z^2=9$
$20+60z+45z^2=0$
$\frac{45z^2}{45}+\frac{60z}{45}+\frac{20}{45}=z^2+\frac{4z}{3}+\frac{4}{9}=0$
$(z=\frac{2}{3})^2=0$
$z=\frac{-2}{3}$ ---> $x=\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Have you tried plugging in $x=\frac53 -3yz$ in the other equation to get $(\frac53-3yz)^2 +y^2+z^2=1$ ?

Comment: That is essentially what he did ! :-)

Answer (score 1):

A bit more simplification will give you
$$(81y^2+9)z^2-90yz+(9y^2+16)=0\ .$$
Treat this as a quadratic in $z$: for real solutions, the discriminant must be non-negative,
$$(90y)^2-4(81y^2+9)(9y^2+16)\ge0\ .$$
A bit of work turns this into
$$(9y^2-4)^2\le0$$
and so $y=\pm\frac23$.

Since this was basically what you were asking I'll leave the rest up to you :)

Comment: How did you go from the first step shown to the second (treating it as a quadratic in z)? I think understand the $(90y)^2$ (though wouldn't it be $90y^2$?), but taking what you got as a whole, I got $8100y^2-2916y^4+5508y^2+576$, which doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: The second step is the discriminant commonly written as $b^2-4ac$.

Comment: For your expression with $y^4$ etc, collect the $y^2$ terms and cancel lots of factors from the coefficients.  There is a fair bit of algebra but it's all pretty basic, you just have to keep going and not give up :)

Comment: Well, $y=\frac{-2}{3}$ worked out okay, but I got multiple values for $z$ and $x$ with $y=\frac{2}{3}$, as shown in the work added above. I think I might have done something wrong. (If you're fed up with my shenanigans, I can see about finding help from someone else.)

Comment: If you look at my first equation and substitute $y=\frac23$ you can see that the quadratic should be $45z^2-60z+20=0$.  (Just like the other one is $45z^2+60z+20=0$.)  I can't see quite where your working went wrong.